# Formula for perimeter of projected figure

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, area, surfaces

Given a surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can calculate the area of its projection $S'$ onto a given plane $P$ using the formula $[S'] = \iint_{S} \cos\beta \space dA$, where $\beta$ is the angle between the surface and $P$ at a given point on $S$.

Is there a corresponding formula for the perimeter of a surface projected onto a plane? It seems like it would be messier, since not all lengths are scaled equally under projection.

Comment: What about $\int_{\partial S}\cos\beta\,ds$?

Comment: I don't think the above formula works. In the case that $S$ is a polygon that lies on a single plane $Q$, then if you have a side $AB$ of $S$ that lies parallel to the plane $P$, the projected length of $AB$ will equal its original length, even if $\beta \neq 0$.

Comment: Of course in this case $\beta$ should represent the angle between between the line and $P$ at a given point.